# Logging Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, logging, flutter

Any idea how to get firebase logs (log on db connection and events etc) on an APK? I would like to send my app to a couple of friends in different countries to test out the app but I am not sure how I can log all the errors by their use more specific to firebase. 
All help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: https://github.com/sabdulm/se-mmh-app
Above is the link to the app for which this needs to be implemented. The real issue I am having is that the firebase is accessible from Pakistan and US but not from UK. Only of my friends in UK were able to load the list within the app which is fetched from firebase. I tried asking the firebase team for help but they say that they have no idea how to solve this without logs. 
So the problem now is that I need logs but I need to do that after sending APK file to my friends in UK.